# Make Outlook appointments for other people -- only show self as free

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2007

I create appointments in Outlook for my managers at work that I do not need to attend. How do I only show myself as "free?" I know there is a setting to do this, but it has happened that when I set myself as free, my managers also show up as free. I only want to set myself as free in case I need to do something else at that same time.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Would these other managers be willing to delegate some of their calendar rights to you? If so, you could create the meetings/appointments from their delegated calendar, and then you wouldn't be automatically added as the organizer.

Comment: Some other ideas here: https://superuser.com/q/562671/766217

Comment: I could ask if they would like to delegate their calendar rights. That is a good idea. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: You can refer to this thread: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/340bb8b5-557f-4090-aafe-6f0f5f37e517/outlook-2013-delegate?forum=outlook

Answer (score 1):

If you send the invite as "busy", then right-click it in the calendar, choose "show as", and then select "free", the invite will only change on your calendar.

Comment: This is what I usually do and it seems to work but every now and then the managers will report that they also showed as free. This seems to happen with reoccurring events.